# Using @property With a Custom Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I've created a custom UITextField with the following code:

## `textField.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface textField : UITextField
@end
```

## `textField.m`

```
#import "textField.h"

@implementation textField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 261, 30) cornerRadius: 2];
    [UIColor.whiteColor setStroke];
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1;
    [rectanglePath stroke];

}

@end
```

But whenever I try:
`@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet textField *textbox;`
I get an error asking if I meant "UITextBox" but if I use "UITextBox" the application crashes.  Any idea as to how I can create custom properties?

Comment: Why do you need a UITextField property inside of a UITextField subclass?

Comment: I need it to go inside my ViewController.m so that I can retrieve text from it as well as dismiss the keyboard later on.

Comment: Show the .h file where you try to add the property for your outlet?

Comment: Stylistic point — classes should begin with a capital letter, like `TextField` rather than `textField`. The latter format is used for variables. That way, it's easy to tell what's a type and what's a variable name.

Comment: @ffz Thanks for the pointer, I never remember stuff like that, but I really try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think your forgot to

```
#import "textField.h"
```

on the ViewController that you are using custom UITextField "**textField**"

Whoever downvote me, this is NOT a comment. See the screen shot.

**Before  #import "textField.h"**

[image]

**After  #import "textField.h"**

[image]

Comment: Look again, it's the very first line.

Comment: Nope. I believe he is using textField.h in another ViewController. Therefore he got the error.

Comment: @voyage11 I didn't down vote but you should clarify your answer by stating where the import is missing.

Comment: Ok, I just added more explanation. I hope that clarify to everyone who downvote me.

Comment: It worked, I'll vote as best answer whenever I can.  Thanks a lot man!